# Плавное перемещение по сетке

Tags: jquery, transition, css, javascript

Ломаю голову не могу придумать...
Есть сетка, предположим из элементов `div`. Вдруг, какой то элемент, пропадает (удаляется) и вся сетка съезжает на одну позицию вверх (заполняя пустое место).
все эти элементы съезжают в один момент, и это смориться ужасно.
Сам вопрос: как сделать перемещение этих элементов плавно?
(Что то подобное есть у Apple в iOS, при удалении иконок с рабочего стола)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить пару вариантов. Правда оба далеки от идеала... особенно под утро ))

1. [Вариант первый](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/37pdp/) (или с немного [измененной анимацией](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/37pdp/1/)). Недостатки будут видны, когда несколько раз потестите.
2. [Второй вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/37pdp/2/). Реализован предельно просто, эффект слабый, да и не во всех случаях может быть применим.

P.S. Забыл добавить, что в примерах, для удаления элемента - кликайте по нему.